# A Small Piece Of The Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

*These images seem a bit off, don't you think?*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkNSS.png]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The answer will be one word.**

Comment: Is there a checksum for the answer? Will it be obvious? I can get a lot of different words.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer. I'd post this in a comment but I can't think of a good way to hide it.

> xkcd [231](https://xkcd.com/231/) [117](https://xkcd.com/117/) [217](https://xkcd.com/217/) [107](https://xkcd.com/107/)

Comment: [rot47](https://rot47.net/) works well for this kind of thing.